# Maria DB still can't save utf8 word

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mariadb

I set `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
```

and  `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-clients.cnf`

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

And `SET NAMES UTF8`

But still can't save chinese words

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Some* Chinese "characters" require 4 *bytes*.  `utf8mb4` (instead of `utf8`) was designed for them.  Please provide an example of a few Chinese words you could not 'save', plus what you get when you try to `SELECT` them.

Also provide

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM table WHERE ...
```

so we can see if they got stored correctly.  (Versus being displayed incorrectly.)

Comment: I find out it's frontend didn't set utf8